# How to display values in perl html table?

Tags: perl, html-table, html-email

I've the below HTML code inside a perl file where I'm sending a mail. The mail part and html part is fine, but when I try to add perl code inside DATA as `$BStatus` and `$AStatus` its showing as it is! Values for the above two variables is already present and I confirmed it.

How do I display its values?

```
$tme=localtime();
$subject='Android Results';
use MIME::Lite;
my $msg = MIME::Lite->new (
  Subject => $subject,
  From    => 'xyz@gmail.com',
  To      => 'xyz@gmail.com',
  Type    => 'text/html',
  Data    => '<H1>Summary</H1><br> <table border="1"> <tr bgcolor="#87CEFA"> <th>Platforms</th> <th>BStatus</th> <th>AStatus</th> <th>Results</th> </tr>  <tr> <th bgcolor="#87CEFA">123</th> <td>$kstatus</td> <td>$astatus</td> <td> <a href="http://xx.xxx.xx.xx/Android/123.html">123-Results</a> </tr>  <tr> <th bgcolor="#87CEFA">atgs</th> <td>row 2, cell 2</td> <td>row 2, cell 3</td> </tr>  <tr> <th bgcolor="#87CEFA">8765</th> <td>row 2, cell 2</td> <td>row 2, cell 3</td> </tr>  <tr></table>'
);
$msg->send();
```

Comment: I would recommend you check out [Template Toolkit](http://template-toolkit.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Perl does not interpolate variables inside single quoted strings.

Use:

- A double quoted string
- One of the alternative syntaxes for double quoted strings such as `qq[...]`
- A proper template system

Comment: Thanks. When i used as "$astatus", perl printed it as it is! when Data was used in quotes as Data => " xxx " i got syntax error.

Comment: Thanks Quentin. It worked using qq(). Can i also know how do i use an if else statement inside an html table as in my code?

Comment: If you want that much logic, then use a real template language. Template-Toolkit is the de facto standard.